# pushing data into array inside a for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could someone give me an explanation as to why this works

```
itemIds = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
  itemIds.push(data[0].item);
}
console.log(itemIds); // outputs as expected, the same thing, data.length times
```

But this does not work (the only change is adding `i` into the `push()`)

```
itemIds = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
  itemIds.push(data[i].item);
}
console.log(itemIds); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined
```

I need to do this as `data` in this example is coming from an angular `$http` call, and returning an object. I don't understand why statically putting in 0 works, but trying to make it iterate through each `data.item` does not.

Comment: try `itemIds.push(data[i][item])`;

Comment: change `<=` to just `<` and you are all good

Comment: @Endless I don't think that solves the problem of pushing `undefined` elements into an array.

Comment: @Endless I have no idea why, but making that change worked, is there any explanation behind that? Seems very weird to me.

Comment: @Philip Chan I tried that method as well, but got the same TypeError: Cannot read property..

Comment: @danielHall explains it very well

Comment: putting a breakpoint in your loop would also explain it very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your variable `i` will eventually increment above the length of the array.

You need to change your for loop from `i <= data.length` to `i < data.length`.

This will ensure that the `i` variable will always be within the bounds of the array.

Considering that the index is zero-based, but the length will count up from one, the length will always be one more than the highest index.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my dummy explanation.

`i` can never be equal to data.lenght

If for example:

```
var data = ['Bob', 'John', 'Mike'];
data[0] = Bob
data[1] = John
data[2] = Mike
data[3] = ?
```

Therefore `data[3]` cannot be equal to `data.length = 3`, it starts looping through 0.

Hope it helps for newbies.

Answer (score 3):

Just to demostrate what goes wrong

```js
basket = ['milk', 'egg', 'chees']

for (var i = 0; i <= basket.length; i++) {
  console.log('loop ' + i, basket[i])
}

/*
Logs: 
loop 0 milk
loop 1 egg
loop 2 chees
loop 3 undefined
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
basket = ['milk', 'egg', 'chees']

var x = "";

for (var i = 0; i <= basket.length; i++) {

x = 'loop ' + i, basket[i];
  console.log(x);
}
```

Hope it solves the problem. 'loop ' + i, basket[i]; -- itself creates an empty unidentified element if is not declared with a variable and variable must have an empty content, like this var x = "";